# AngularJs How to wait for the load of a templateUrl in directive

Tags: angularjs, load, promise, directive

Is it possible to wait that the templateUrl finished to load to execute the controller code?

I thought I will be able to do it with promise but as a beginner I didn't succeed.

for example:

```
controller:DialogController,
templateUrl:'mytemplates/display.html'
```

and then I have:

```
function DialogController($scope){
console.log(document.getElementById('chart')); //=>null
};
```

I would like to get => div id="chart"
(at the moment i can get this answer only with a timeout)

Comment: please check this [URL](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) ,it will be help you to raise your content quality

Answer (score 0):

It means it's not fully loaded. You can add an `EventListener` when page is loaded:

```
addEventListener('load', load, false);

function load(){
  console.log(document.getElementById('chart'));
}
```

Comment: In fact I can't use link function.
the controller and the templateUrl are in a $mdDialog
             $mdDialog.show({
            controller: DialogController,
            templateUrl:'templates/pages/releves/displaygraph.html',
            clickOutsideToClose: true,
            scope: scope,
            preserveScope: true,
          });